# Configure system variables in phoenixweb-framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How do I use System.get_env("ACCESS_KEY_ID")

I have create an config/application.yml file with the content

```
dev:
  access_key_id: ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
```

I have tried to use figaro_elixir and it works as perfect when I test it from the terminal

When I run

```
$ MIX_ENV=dev iex -S mix
iex(1)> System.get_env("ACCESS_KEY_ID")
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMN"
iex(2)>
```

but in my config/dev.exc

I got nothing

```
IO.puts System.get_env("ACCESS_KEY_ID")
```

Any suggestions? I would like not to expose all my secret credentials.

Comment: I.m trying to run $ MIX_ENV=test mix phoenix.server

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for figaro_elixir. Just directly access the environment in your configuration files:

```
# config/dev.exs
config :my_app, :access_key_id, System.get_env("SUPER_SECRET")
```

And then in your application code: `Application.get_env(:my_app, :access_key_id)`. You can also define the configuration above to be simply a string in development and use the environment variable only in `config/prod.exs`.

Another alternative is to explicitly put all secrets in the `config/prod.secrets.exs` file and ensure it is not in your version control but only in your deployment machines.

EDIT: There is no need for a `.yml` based configuration system in Elixir. It is unnecessary complexity. You can do everything and more by using Elixir's configuration system.

Comment: I.m trying to run $ MIX_ENV=test mix phoenix.server  on my localhost:4000  Where should I populate System.get_env("SUPER_SECRET")

Comment: If it is for test, just have it in your config/test.exs. If you need an actual token for test, you can also have "config/test.secret.exs", which you import from config/test.exs but you won't check it into version control (as we do with config/prod.secret.exs).

Answer (score 0):

I finaly got it
`System.get_env("ACCESS_KEY_ID")` 
is a part of my system i.e. my computer. I have to put there myself.
for someone on #slack pointed me to

https://github.com/avdi/dotenv_elixir

Comment: I was having trouble resolving this problem myself while using System.get.env within a prod.secret.exs file.  The values were always empty on the target server, despite being able to echo out the values from the shell.  I didn't realize that these values are resolved at the time the release is built, not pulled at runtime on the target machine.  So the environment variables have to be available on the build machine.